Encountered PydanticSerializationError problem in fastapi
When I run my fastapi web backend program, an error occurs: pydantic_core._pydantic_core.PydanticSerializationError: Unable to serialize unknown type: <class 'model.standard_data_model.Standard_Data_Model'>, which shows that my Standard_Data_Model class cannot be serialized? The code of my Standard_Data_Model class is as follows:
class Standard_Data_Model(declarative_base()):
__tablename__ = 'miun_standard_data'
id = Column(INT, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True, comment='Primary key id')
ros_bag_id = Column(INT, nullable=True, comment='Associated raw data set management')
language_instruction = Column(String(255), nullable=True, comment='Instruction description')
duration = Column(String(255), nullable=True, comment='Duration')
morphology = Column(String(255), nullable=True, comment='Morphology')
robot_type = Column(String(255), nullable=True, comment='Device type')
effector_type = Column(String(255), nullable=True, comment='Gripping type')
device_number = Column(String(255), nullable=True, comment='Device number')
resource_type = Column(String(255), nullable=True, comment='File type')
file_path = Column(String(255), nullable=True, comment='File path')
status = Column(String(255), nullable=True, comment='Status')
task_id = Column(String(255), nullable=True, comment='Task id')
editor = Column(String(255), nullable=True, comment='Editor id')
description = Column(String(255), nullable=True, comment='Description of this message')
tag = Column(String(255), nullable=True, comment='Tag set')
version_num = Column(String(255), nullable=True, comment='Version number')
create_time = Column(DateTime, default=datetime.now(), comment='creation time')
update_time = Column(DateTime, default=None, onupdate=datetime.now(), comment='update time')

def __init__(self, ros_bag_id, language_instruction, duration, morphology, robot_type,
effector_type, device_number, resource_type, file_path, status, task_id,
editor, description, tag, version_num, create_time, update_time):
self.ros_bag_id = ros_bag_id
self.language_instruction = language_instruction
self.duration = duration
self.morphology = morphology
self.robot_type = robot_type
self.effector_type = effector_type
self.device_number = device_number
self.resource_type = resource_type
self.file_path = file_path
self.status = status
self.task_id = task_id
self.editor = editor
self.description = description
self.tag = tag
self.version_num = version_num
self.create_time = create_time
self.update_time = update_time

I encapsulated the CRUD methods for the database in the dal layer of the project. I modified one of the methods today. Yesterday, my code could start normally without any errors, but after I modified the code today, the above error appeared. I wonder if it is related to the method I modified?
This method is as follows before modification:
def find_by_id(self, id : int) -> Optional[Standard_Data_Model]:
data = self.session.execute(
select(Standard_Data_Model).where(Standard_Data_Model.id == id)
)
res = data.scalars().first()
return res

This method is as follows after modification:
def find_by_id(self, id : int, _filter: str) -> Optional[Standard_Data_Model]:
if _filter:
data = self.session.execute(
select(Standard_Data_Model).where(
(Standard_Data_Model.id == id) & (Standard_Data_Model.language_instruction == _filter)
)
)
else:
data = self.session.execute(
select(Standard_Data_Model).where(Standard_Data_Model.id == id)
)
res = data.scalars().first()
return res


You can use model_config and from_attributes to allow a pydantic model to be populated from an SQLAlchemy object - but it would still require a Pydantic definition of the model to be returned.

The error says it all: somewhere in your code you create a Pydantic model that uses your Standard_Data_Model.
That's why u get this error message:

pydantic_core.PydanticSerializationError: Unable to serialize unknown
type: <class 'model.standard_data_model.Standard_Data_Model'>

Pydantic itself does not know how to serialize object like this (because it's SQLAlchemy model)
Probably you are trying to return some response using pydantic right after you fetched your data from the database, but dont't perform serialization. What you need to do is to create a response pydantic model that would have the records you need and serialize your database object using this model.
Example pseudo-code:
class StandardDataModelResponse(BaseModel):
    id: int
    other_field_you_need_to_include_in_response: type_of_field


database_records = Standard_Data_Model.query.all()
response = StandardDataModelResponse(**database_records.to_dict())
return response


I already have a Response body
      data:Optional[dict]=Field(default={})```
And other models can also run normally, but only the Standard_Data_Model model has an exception. I don’t know why

Please, provide code where you form a response with your Standard_Data_Model data

I don't know the reason now, but when I restored the code I modified today to yesterday's state and rewrote the code, the previous error disappeared. From the result, it seems that there is no problem. Thank you for your advice and help
